# How to setup QMAIL SERVER to store the emails sent?

Tags: email, qmail

I need to store all emails sent through the mail server Qmail.

I searched folders Qmail and can not find it.

I am working with Ubuntu 12.4

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using qmail-tap feature:

```
# touch /var/qmail/control/taps
# vi /var/qmail/control/taps
# To tap whole emails of the domain:
.*@userDomainName.com:bcc@yourMailAddressToRcvCopy.com

# To tap individual email address:
email@userDomain.com:your@MailAddressToRcvCopy.com
```

Comment: Please always mark answer if helped you so that new visitors can apply the solution without any hassle. It also provide us immense pleasure to have +15 points as well as spiritual satisfaction that we were useful for someone